# Is there a word for my ex-spouse's new spouse?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, kinship-terms

With modern high divorce rates, a lot of people get married more than once in their lives. Saying "my ex-wife's new husband" is a bit awkward. Is there anything more graceful?

I came across it in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqXGxLWPWMQ. They proposed "ex-in-law" and "outlaw", mostly in jest.

Comment: "Your replacement"

Comment: If I'd have been a woman, I'd probably call my ex-husband's new partner his [floozie](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/floozy) and I'd spell it that way too, regardless of what the link says.

Comment: *Outlaws* are the people who would be your inlaws had you made an honest woman of your girlfriend.

Comment: @ΜετάEd: No question. There are so many of them now that people just use the word without thinking there's making any attempt to be funny. It's just part of the normal vocab for many people in my neck of the woods.

Comment: It appears that women who marry a man with an ex-wife are sometimes simply called *second wives*. There is the Second Wives Club and the online group known as the [Second Wives Cafe](http://secondwivescafe.com/). I suppose the term *second husband* could be used as well. (Even if accurate, these terms feel a bit disparaging.)

Comment: @JLG - true, undoubtedly.  But if the first husband referred to his replacement as "my second husband", I suspect people would get the wrong idea.

Comment: 'Her latest squeeze'?

Comment: How about the "guy who's banging my wife" for boyfriend of ex-wife or the "guy who's wishing he was banging my wife" for husband of ex-wife.

Comment: "My step-me".  Which can be elaborated to "my wicked step-me" if you wish.

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't.

This sort of kinship relation is relatively new to Anglophone cultures, and there are really no established norms to follow. It takes centuries for terms like this to populate the language and its culture.

Really, you have two options -- or more correctly, a mix of the two:

1. explain the nature of the relation (once) to anyone who's that interested in it
2. make up a relation(al term) that will pass under people's radar, and stick to it.

*Counterpartner* is a reasonable and logical relational term, which unfortunately means that nobody's ever heard of it, and likely won't understand it.

But maybe it'll make them ask, if that's what you want.

Comment: I agree: I think _my ex's new spouse_ would be much more understandable than _my counterpartner_, and it doesn't even add an extra syllable.

Comment: 'Anglophone' -->  'most'

Comment: True, but this is an English language question.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to be friendly, then *my daughter’s stepfather* might fit the bill [substitute appropriate offspring as necessary]. Why mention the ex-wife/partner at all?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't need to be unfriendly; this could be used matter-of-factly as well. I can think of contexts where this would work rather nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Try *counterpartner.* [This article](http://www.bonusfamilies.com/articles/counterpartners.php) from a site supporting blended or bonus families is written from the woman's perspective relating to the other wife/mother, but I see no reason why *counterpartner* can't be applied to the ex-husband relating to the new husband/father. However *counterpartner* doesn't appear in dictionaries yet.

Note also the bonus term *bonus mom*, which is probably a friendlier way to distinguish between the biological mother and the new mom (a.k.a. stepmother), and from which *bonus dad* could be extrapolated.