# half-siblings - adults' relationship

Tags: kinship-terms

I was married and we had a daughter. We divorced. My ex-husband remarried and has a son. Our daughter and his son are half-siblings - share a dad. What am I to his son? What is his new wife to my daughter - stepmother I think?

Comment: Yes regarding the stepmother. As for what you are to his son, I don't believe English has a word for this. "My dad's ex-wife" is accurate but unsatisfying.

Comment: Does your daughter live with you, or with your ex-husband and his second wife?

Comment: Related: 1. [Is there a word for my relation to ex-wife's child?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148717/is-there-a-word-for-my-relation-to-ex-wifes-child/148759#148759) and 2. [Is there a word for my ex-spouse's new spouse?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81120/is-there-a-word-for-my-ex-spouses-new-spouse)

Answer (score 1):

[Stepmother](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stepmother?q=step+mother) is a woman:

> ***who is married to*** one’s father after the divorce of one’s parents or the death of one’s mother.

The relationship is established only when you are (legally) married to a man who had a child or children with his ex-wife or deceased wife. You would be his/her *would-be stepmother* if you are planning to marry him.

You are just an ex-wife or friend (if you maintain friendship with him) of his father. There is no legal relationship between you and him. The same applies to the relationship between your daughter and your ex-husband's new wife.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: "of his son's father" seems to me like it must be changed to "of his father" to make sense.

Comment: Well, it would also make sense if you said "of your son's father." It's the "his" that didn't work for me.

Comment: @sumelic You are right.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I read it as meaning "the same applies to the relationship between your daughter and your ex-husband's new wife."